# At linux OS Use subprocess fork a process always can not download picture

Tags: python, linux

```
path='/home/loading/image/img'+str(self.username)+'.jpg'
imgurl=http://i.meizitu.net/thumbs/2016/07/68989_12a19_236.jpg

cmd=("wget -P -N -o -c{0}{1}".format(path,imgurl))
ref=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
if ref!=0:
  print "can't get url"
```

modified corresponding code cmd=("wget -P -N -o -c {0}{1}".format(path,imgurl))
the `path` and `imgurl` is all right ,all i have already made sure of it by python libraty of urlretrieve , but now print  "can't get url" cannot download picture！

Comment: Aren't you missing some quotes around the URL? Or some spaces between the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot a space after the '-c' and the order of the path and imgurl is probabli incorrect since the 'http://' is usually the beginning of the url :-)

```
 path='/home/loading/image/img'+str(self.username)+'.jpg'
 imgurl='http://i.meizitu.net/thumbs/2016/07/68989_12a19_236.jpg'

 cmd=("wget -P -N -o -c {1}{0}".format(path,imgurl))
 ref=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
 if ref!=0:
    print "can't get url"
```

Comment: This is still missing a crucial part: A single space between the two last arguments.

Comment: add a space after ‘-c‘ but  print "can't get url"   can not download this picture at this path

Comment: In case the path is the path for saving the image, you have to add '-O' switch
`"wget -P -N -o -c -O {0} {1}".format(path,imgurl)`

Comment: why i can not put these" wget parameters" in random ? otherwise cause a error ?

Comment: because '-O' takes the filename as parameter.

Comment: switch  cmd=("wget -o -c -N -P -O {0} {1}".format(path,img)) why print “get a url ” raise a error？